# cyrillic in windows Console(java) System.out.println();

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8

When i write some cyrillic text, System.out.println("Русский язык") - then it outpus this ╨єёёъшщ  ч√ъ, using windows console, how can be this fixed?, the file encoding is utf-8, but it doesn't matter, when it was ansii or windows-1251, it were outputing the same.

Comment: I don't believe the Windows console supports Unicode output...

Comment: Depending on how you execute your java code this articule might helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line-how

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
class Kyrill {
    public static void main(String args[])
        throws java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException
    {
        String ru = "Русский язык";
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
        System.out.println(ru.length());
        System.out.println(ru);
        ps.println(ru);
    }
}

D:\Temp :: chcp 65001
Aktive Codepage: 65001.

D:\Temp :: javac -encoding utf-8 Kyrill.java && java Kyrill
12
??????? ????
Русский языкй язык
```

Note that you might see some trailing junk in the output (I do) but if you redirect the output to a file you'll see that this is just a display artefact.

So you can make it work by using a [PrintStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html). The [System.out](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) uses the platform encoding (cp1252 for me), and that doesn't have cyrillic characters.

Additional note for you to grok the encoding business:

```
D:\Temp :: chcp 1251
Aktive Codepage: 1251.
:: This is another codepage (8 bits only) that maps bytes to cyrillic characters.
:: Edit the source file to have:
::      PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "Windows-1251");
:: We intend to match the console output; else we won't get the expected result.
D:\Temp :: javac -encoding utf-8 Kyrill.java && java Kyrill
12
??????? ????
Русский язык
```

So you can see that contrary to what some people believe, the Windows console *does grok Unicode* in the casual sense that it can print Greek and Russian.

Comment: I copied the first part of your code and did exactly as you said, but the output is still a mess. So what you saw seems not a universal truth for all windows consoles. Note: I am using windows 7 64 bits, professional, English version.

Comment: @dragon66 - Did you use UTF-8 as the source file encoding? If not, that's the reason for your mess. Else, define "mess".

Comment: Yes, I did and these are the mess I saw:

C:\work-temp>javac -encoding utf-8 Kyrill.java

C:\work-temp>javac -encoding utf-8 Kyrill.java && java Kyrill
12
??????? ????
╨á╤â╤ü╤ü╨║╨╕╨╣ ╤Å╨╖╤ï╨║

Comment: It looks like you missed the `chcp 65001` command to switch your console window to UTF-8.

Comment: No, I just didn't include it in the comment.

Answer (score 2):

Although you can switch Windows console to UTF-8 by chcp 65001, you may still not be able to view UTF-8 output properly. This may not be what you want, but it at least is a choice: redirect your standard output to a file. Save your source file as UTF-8 and compile it using UTF-8 encoding. The redirected output file can be viewed with a UTF-8 aware text editor.

```
String s = "Русский язык";
System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("out.txt"), true, "UTF-8"));
System.out.println(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

Windows console uses encoding CP866 for Cyrillic, for historical reasons (remember DOS?). Windows console is definitely not Unicode-capable.

(Alas, I have no Windows machine around to provide a tested code snippet.)

Comment: This is wrong. First, `cmd.exe` is not "DOS", and implying it is related is misleading. Second, it is "Unicode-capable" in the way in which the OP is trying to make it work.

Comment: @Lumi: (1) DOS of old 16-bit days used the encoding known now as CP866. Modern 32- and 64-bit Windows have to follow the suit, despite using another 8-bit Cyrillic encoding (CP1251) in the GUI part, and proper Unicode in Unicode API. (2) 'Unicode-capable' would be capable of at least displaying all of Base Plane characters; Windows console only supported 8-bit encodings last time I checked. If this has changed, it's welcome news.

Comment: This sounds correct. The welcome news is simply ["65001 utf-8 Unicode (UTF-8)"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756.aspx). Full BMP support means many, many languages, also right-to-left ones like Arabic, and that might require a different version of `cmd.exe`, and of course you need to have an appropriate console font installed, and I'm not sure it even exists, probably yes, but I've never seen it.