# Java: checkError() for PrintWriter(OutputStreamWriter(System.out))

Tags: java

Trying to change the encoding of System.out, I created a PrintWriter with

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out, ENCODING));
```

so

```
out.format("some text");
```

worked fine as for the encoding. But

```
out.checkError()
```

didn't return true
when the output stream was closed, e.g. by Unix 'head' command.

I've found that PrintStream offers a constructor with encoding

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, ENCODING);
```

and the checkError()
worked fine for this class.

I doubt the PrintWriter case is a bug, or am I missing something?

Comment: What is the expected result? What are You trying to achieve?

Comment: The output stream isn't closed by the `head` command. Only you can close it.

Answer (score 0):

No, I also think that this is not a bug, but roots in a subtly different definition/design of `checkError()` and its underlying classes:

- [PrintWriter.checkError()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#checkError--):

  > `public boolean checkError()`
  >   Flushes the stream *if it's not closed* and checks its error state.
  >   *Returns:`true` if the print stream has encountered an error*, either on the underlying output stream or during a format conversion.
- and from [PrintStream.checkError()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#checkError--):

  > `public boolean checkError()` Flushes the stream and checks its error state. The internal error state is set to `true` when the underlying output stream throws an `IOException` other than `InterruptedIOException`, and when the `setError` method is invoked. If an operation on the underlying output stream throws an `InterruptedIOException`, then the `PrintStream` converts the exception back into an interrupt by doing:
  >    `Thread.currentThread().interrupt();` 
  >   or the equivalent.
  >   Returns:
  >   `true` if and only if this stream has encountered an `IOException` other than `InterruptedIOException`, or the `setError` method has been invoked.

As you see `PrintStream`'s `checkError()`definition is the stricter one, and the fail maybe still worth an investigation.

And then much depends from your actual output console (and the encodings it supports.), e.g. in Windows, you **need** to:

```
chcp 65001
```

..to enable (e.g.) UTF-8 output.(https://stackoverflow.com/a/388500/592355, https://stackoverflow.com/a/10148976/592355, ...)