# How to solve the error in taking the Cyrillic language characters in Java

Tags: java

My actual file name is "**парламент.xls**".

But I am unable to get the same file name in `java`. It was coming something strange like **???????.xls**
The problem is coming for the non-latin words and characters.
How to use my actual file name without being changed.

I tried from my side. Please refer to my below code:

```
String escaped_source = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(filename);
String encoded = new String(filename.getBytes("UTF-16"), "ISO-8859-1");
System.out.println("escaped_source------------>"+escaped_source);
System.out.println("encoded------------>"+encoded);
String abc = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(escaped_source);
System.out.println("abc------------>"+abc);
```

Output:
escaped_source------------

```
>\u043F\u0430\u0440\u043B\u0430\u043C\u0435\u043D\u0442.xls
encoded------------>þÿ?0@;0<5=B
abc------------>?????????.xls
```

Comment: rename your file would be the easiest solve

Answer (score 0):

System.out uses platform encoding. This question is already answered 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143998/cyrillic-in-windows-consolejava-system-out-println)

Comment: Don't link to a duplicate, mark the question as a duplicate.

Comment: Actually i have to pass this file name to a function by storing it in a string variable. How can i store this file name without being changed. The above solutions are given for printing in the console alone. So how to store the exact file name in a string variable???