# Unicode file handling in java

Tags: java, unicode

```
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("g.txt"), "UTF-16"));
ArrayList<String> al=new ArrayList<String>();
String str;
while((str=br.readLine())!=null)
{
    al.add(str);
}
Iterator<String> it=al.iterator();
while(it.hasNext())
{
    str=it.next();
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

In this code I can read data from Unicode file properly and also able to insert into arrylist correctly but while I am trying to iterate the data It just print question marks only like
????
??
????, ?????,
and so on
can you help to solve this issu

Answer (score 0):

This question [has been answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143998/cyrillic-in-windows-consolejava-system-out-println) on StackOverflow already and it has to do with System.out.println() using the default system codepage, not the set locale.

To print text using correct character encoding, create a new instance of PrintStream and use that to print your lines of text:

```
String text_containing_non_latin_characters = "...";
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-16");
ps.println(text_containing_non_latin_characters);
```